# Append general buffer to the end of every line in VI

Tags: text, replace, buffer, vi

I'm trying to add the contents of the general buffer to the end of every line. I'm sure this is fairly simple, however, an hour of google searches have lead me nowhere.

This is what my file looks like

> ::Things to bring camping
>   --matches
>   --tent
>   --sleeping bags
>   --inflatable bed
>   --firewood
>   --camping stove
>   --skillet

I want to add "::Things to bring camping" to the end of every line.

This is i have figured out so far.

1. */::* -> brings me to the line in question
2. *Y* -> yanks the entire line to the general buffer
3. I tried *:%s/$/\p* -> this added a "*p*" to the end of every line.

My problem is with step 3.  How do I tell the "search and replace command" to used the "*p*" (the contents of the general buffer) instead of the "*p*" the character

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: If you try doing it with a macro, you will be able to use 'p' to add the contents of the general buffer.

Answer (score 0):

For step three, instead of \p, you should use ctrl-R-a.  Hold down the control key and type an uppercase "R", continue holding control, and type a lowercase "a".

For a line with multiple words, use ctrl-R-" instead.

Comment: This almost does it. However this only paste the first word *::Things*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had to go into vim and find out.

The way to copy your entire line while in command mode, is:

^r "

(that's CTRL and r, then " )

That should paste the entire line you yanked into your search and replace command

Comment: Thank you very much.  One last thing.  How do I get rid of the ^M.

Comment: if you already search and replaced, then just do another search and replace to replace it with nothing, like this: %s/^M//g

Comment: it would actually be like this:  %s/\^M/
(the other slash "escapes" the special character "^")

Comment: actually the command you type is %s/^v^m//g - control v will allow you to type the control M

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using a macro - they're very powerful.
In this case I took your list example and positioned it at the first colon. 
I used y$ to grab the remainder of the line in the buffer.
Then I recorded the macro - I chose 1.
q1
j$pq

Then you can call it for any number of rows in your list. E.g. 10@1

Answer (score 0):

Learned something figuring this one out ...

```
:%s/$/\=getreg()/
```

The \= says that what follows is an expression to be evaluated, and the getreg() call gets the contents of the register, by default the "general buffer" as it used to be called by vi.